# CKEDITOR iterate over all elements in body

Tags: javascript, dom, ckeditor, iteration

I would like to iterate over all elements inside the body tag in CKEDITOR. I am trying this way:

```
document.getBody().getChildren()
```

But it returns some strange collection, which is not usable to iterate. Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To easily iterate over all elements you can use a small trick:

```
var elements = editor.document.getBody().getElementsByTag( '*' );

for ( var i = 0; i < elements.count(); ++i ) {
    console.log( elements.getItem( i ).getName() );
}
```

But remember that `elements` is a wrapped native DOM **live** collection. So basically it's risky to modify DOM during iterating, because it may change that collection.

BTW. It's not a "some strange collection". Have you checked [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/)? All this is documented - what's returned from `getChildren()` and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine. But it is badly documented in the version 3 - http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.element.html#getChildren